# enable command button on form while in filterbyform mode

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to put a pair of command buttons onto a form to enable users to:

1. enter filter criteria, then
2. after they enter the criteria, apply the filter

The first is easy enough with "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFilterByForm"

The second would work with "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdApplyFilterSort", except that I can't figure out how to activate my command button "cmdApplyFilter". The code "Me.cmdApplyFilter.Enabled = True" throws a runtime error.

I've looked at a lot of discussions, and it seems the only way to do this is by clicking on the ribbon or quick access toolbar. Does anyone know how to activate a command button on the form while in filter by form mode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you're trying to achieve is not possible. The 'filter by form' view of the form looks to be a copy of your original form with only the input controls enabled to allow you to enter your filter criteria. If you think about it, it wouldn't make sense to allow full functionality. If you could activate buttons in this mode then you would theoretically be able to perform all sorts of actions that aren't appropriate in this context: add records, delete records, navigate through the records etc.

I suspect that the only way you will be able to get the functionality you want without using the ribbon bar buttons (what's wrong with the ribbon bar?) is to hand-roll your own filter form. Design a new form having controls to accept filter criteria and buttons to cancel or apply the filter. Sounds like a lot of hard work though to replicate functionality that's already built into Access out of the box.

Comment: You may be right. I've "rolled my own" forms with more complex filter criteria, but was just thinking there had to be a better way than training users to find the icon on the ribbon (or Quick Access Toolbar) and click it there. But it looks like there isn't. Thanks.